# How to order by last name in laravel controller return value using foreach loop

Tags: laravel, sorting, join, subquery

> I tried to put `orderBy(hr_workers.l_name)` before `get()` but it's not working.. also tried to put it on $workers but still not working... I don't have any idea why isn't working...
> anyone can help me all answer must be appreciated thanks in advance

I want the result is alphabetically arrange by last name

```
public function show6($id)
    {

    $workers = DB::table('hr_workers')
    ->select('wrk_id','f_name','m_name','l_name');

    $attendance = DB::table('payroll_daily_attendance')->where('payroll_daily_id', $id)
    ->select('payroll_daily_attendance.*','f_name','l_name','m_name')
    ->rightjoinSub($workers,'worker', function($join){
        $join->on('payroll_daily_attendance.wrk_id','=','worker.wrk_id');
    });
   
    $payroll = DB::table('payroll_daily_details')
    ->select('payroll_daily_details.*','wrk_id','f_name','m_name','l_name','attendance.*')
    ->rightjoinSub($attendance,'attendance', function($join){
        $join->on('payroll_daily_details.payroll_daily_id','=','attendance.payroll_daily_id');
    })
    
    ->get();

    $fetch = [];
    foreach($payroll as $key){
         if(!isset($fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_ot']) && !isset($fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_days']) && !isset($fetch[$key->wrk_id]['grand_total'])){
            $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_ot'] = 0;
            $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_days'] = 0;
            $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_allowance'] = 0;
            $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['grand_total'] = 0;
          }
            $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['wrk_id'] = $key->wrk_id;
            $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['f_name'] = $key->f_name;
            $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['l_name'] = $key->l_name;
            $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['m_name'] = $key->m_name;
            $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_days'] += $key->reg_hour + $key->adj_hour;
            $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_allowance'] += $key->allowance;
         
          
      }
      return $fetch;


    }
```

Comment: `hr_workers` is not a valid alias at the top level of your query, and ordering in a subquery without limit is generally ignored. But you should be able to `orderBy('l_name')` at the top level

Comment: `orderBy('l_name')` where can I put this?

Comment: On the `$payroll = ...` query before the `->get()`

Comment: not working bro.. ordering by last name doesn't  affect when I used foreach to return value?

Comment: @Nick  try to return $payroll orderBy('l_name') is working but on my code I need to return the data which in the $fetch

Comment: The `$fetch` array should have the same `l_name` ordering as the `$payroll` result set, assuming the `wrk_id` values are always associated with the same `l_name`. How are you displaying the results?

Comment: I'm using vuejs for the front end.. The result of `$fetch` in to network tab is isn't ordered by l_name but when I try to return the $payroll Its working.. but in my case I need to return the data from `$fetch` not in `$payroll`

Comment: Do some of the `wrk_id` values have more than one `l_name` associated with them? That could account for it. In which case you would need to sort `$fetch` by the `l_name` value, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: Exactly I think $fetch array would be sort by l_name

Comment: @nick I have no Idea how can I do it on my code

Comment: before `return $fetch` use `usort($fetch, function($a, $b) { return $a['l_name'] <=> $b['l_name']; });`

Comment: It's Working !! I appreciate your help bro thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there can be multiple `l_name` values associated with each `wrk_id` in the  `$fetch` array, any `l_name` ordering in the query will be overwritten because of the way the `$fetch` array is being generated. You need to sort the `$fetch` array by the `l_name` value before you return it, which you can do using this method (derived from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)):

```php
usort($fetch, function($a, $b) { return $a['l_name'] <=> $b['l_name']; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$payroll = DB::table('payroll_daily_details')
->select('payroll_daily_details.*','wrk_id','f_name','m_name','l_name','attendance.*')
->rightjoinSub($attendance,'attendance', function($join){
    $join->on('payroll_daily_details.payroll_daily_id','=','attendance.payroll_daily_id');
})
->orderBy('l_name')
->get();
```

Comment: Can you send more information about the error?

Comment: It display the data but isn't sorted by l_name

Answer (score 0):

As was highlighted by Euclides Cardoso Junior. I believe for you to have your results arranged alphabetically you need to put the second parameter to the orderBy function to entail the order to be followed and also put the group by function. Check the code below;
`$yourQuery->orderBy('l_name', 'asc') ->groupBy('l_name') ->get();`

Hope this is helpful.